# Sublime text remove multy cursor selection in windows

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to remove selection when you use multy cursors. I mean when I use `ctrl+d` it expandes selection and `ctrl+k, ctrl+d` to skip selection works, but `ctrl+u` for removing selection is not working on windows. Is there another shortcut or some snippents to make it work?

Comment: do you want to remove all selections or just the most recent one?

Comment: just the recent one, the `ctrl+u` is suppose to work on mack, and it's not working for me on windows.

Comment: There must be a plugin or something interfering with it. Try this: open the console with `Ctrl-\`` and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Then, leaving the console open, try doing a multiple selection with `ctrl-d`. You should see the console list `command: find_under_expand`. Then, try `ctrl-u` and let me know what prints. It should be `soft_undo`, but if it isn't the name of it should help you track down the plugin.

Comment: THANK YOU, some Emmet command `"action": "update_image_size"` was using the same shotcut, I just overrided in user keys. Once again THAKS. Now how to make ure post as answer -).

Comment: BTW, is there any way to clear console in sublime? Like cls in command prompt.

Comment: glad I could help! Please see my answer below - I explained how to troubleshoot step-by-step. In response to your question, no there isn't a way to clear the console, as it's actually an embedded Python interpreter. Just use `sublime.log_commands(False)` to turn off logging, that's about the best you can do.

Comment: I think hold alt button and press mouse middle button may solve your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like there is a plugin interfering with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> undo option. To find it, open the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and enter the command

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

This shows what's going on behind the scenes when you press key combinations or use mouse buttons. Test it by making some multiple selections with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, and you should see

```
command: find_under_expand
```

in the console. Now, try to undo one of your selections by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and see what comes up. If you see

```
command: soft_undo
```

then it's not another plugin issue, as that's what you'd expect to see. However, if (as I suspect) another plugin **is** interfering, you'll see something else there. If you do, hopefully you'll be able to trace it to the plugin it belongs to and disable it.

When you're done, enter

```
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

in the console to turn logging off, then close the console by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>.